# where condition have a declared variable on a wrong place do not know if its valid

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-in

I have a statement like this below in one of my big stored proc, and I am wondering if this is valid to write this way.

```
SELECT  @PVDate = pv.Date,
        @PVdMBeginDate = dbo.fPVoidDate(pv.myID)
FROM PVMeter pv (NOLOCK)
WHERE pv.PR_ID = @PR_ID
AND @VCommen BETWEEN pv.PVDMDate AND dbo.fPVoidDate(pv.myID)
```

Now, here, my question is, @VCommen is a declared date variable with a value set on it. It is not at all a column of PVMeter, while PVDMDate is a column in PVMeter and fpVoidDate returns datetime

While I debug SP, I do not see the value on @PVDate and @PVDMBeginDate

Comment: This looks fine.  Does it work?

Comment: The T-SQL parser would show a syntax error, if it can't understand certain construct. In this case the syntax seems OK. As for why the query doesn't return rows, you should check the logic, your data and values of variables in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Uhmm I never come across such style of query writing in where condition, could you explain the date between thing in where? I am afraid the SP just passes this place of statements, do not know whats happening, when I do quicklook @ pv.myID, it says " it cannot be evaluated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT  
    @PVDate = pv.Date,
    @PVdMBeginDate = dbo.fPVoidDate(pv.myID)
FROM PVMeter pv (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    pv.PR_ID = @PR_ID
    AND pv.PVDMDate <= @VCommen
    AND @VCommen <= dbo.fPVoidDate(pv.myID)
```

This style should be more familiar. In general, you can put any expression in the `WHERE` clause, it can be made of variables or constants without referring to table columns at all.

### Examples

Classic example: `WHERE 1=1 ...` when the query text is generated dynamically. It is easy to add as many expressions as needed in no particular order and prepend all of them with `AND`.

```
DECLARE @VarSQL nvarchar(max);

SET @VarSQL = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 1=1 ';

IF ... THEN SET @VarSQL = @VarSQL + ' AND expression1';
IF ... THEN SET @VarSQL = @VarSQL + ' AND expression2';
IF ... THEN SET @VarSQL = @VarSQL + ' AND expression3';

EXEC @VarSQL;
```

Thus you don't need to have complex logic determining whether you need to add an `AND` before each expression or not.

### Another example.

You have a stored procedure with parameter `@ParamID int`.

You have a complex query in the procedure that usually returns many rows and one column of the result set is some unique `ID`.

```
SELECT ID, ...
FROM ...
WHERE
expression1
AND expression2
AND expression3
...
```

You want to return all rows if `@ParamID` is `NULL` and only one row with the given `ID` if `@ParamID` is not `NULL`. I personally use this approach. When I open the screen with the results of a query for the first time I want to show all rows to the user, so I pass `NULL` as a parameter. Then user makes changes to a selected row, which is done through a separate `UPDATE` statement. Then I want to refresh results that user sees on the screen. I know `ID` of the row that was just changed, so I need to requery just this row, so I pass this `ID` to procedure and fetch only one row instead of the whole table again.

The final query would look like this:

```
SELECT ID, ...
FROM ...
WHERE
(@ParamID IS NULL OR ID = @ParamID)
AND expression1
AND expression2
AND expression3
...
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Thus I don't have to repeat the complex code of the query twice.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me understand this query, but never realize that I could use anything in where which are not related to columns. I have never come across such situations too. Is there any quick examples one for variable and constant in where not relating to a column in table in where?